# Why is RestKit strips my URL, swift?

Tags: swift, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am initing my Object Manager:

```
let baseURL = NSURL(string:"http://xxxxx.net/api")
self.client = AFHTTPClient(baseURL: self.baseURL)
self.objectManager = RKObjectManager(HTTPClient: self.client)
```

But when I run my code:

```
objectManager.getObjectsAtPath("/json.product.gf.php", parameters: queryParameters,
        success: {(requestOperation, mappingResult) -> Void in
            var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            let d = NSDate()
            defaults.setValue(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(d), forKey: "lastProductUpdate")
        },
        failure: {(requestOperation, mappingResult) -> Void in
            NSLog("Failed Products")
    })
```

It errors out because it is stripping "api" from my base url.

Why?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally RKObjectManager probably uses `init?(string URLString: String, relativeToURL baseURL: NSURL?)` to create the new URL from the baseURL and the relative url.

You basically have two problems in your code.

- your baseURL does not end in `/`. The aforementioned API ignores everything behind the last `/` of the baseURL.
- your supposed relative url starts with an `/`. Which means it's actually an absolute URL. This will ignore everything after the host of the baseURL

The position of the slashes is pretty important if you deal with baseURLs. It's an easy fix:

```
let baseURL = NSURL(string:"http://xxxxx.net/api/")
```

and

```
objectManager.getObjectsAtPath("json.product.gf.php", parameters: queryParameters,
```

---

If you have a playground nearby and want to see it yourself:

```
let baseURL = NSURL(string:"http://xxxxx.net/api")! // http://xxxxx.net/api

let url1 = NSURL(string: "json.php", relativeToURL: baseURL)! // http://xxxxx.net/json.php
let url2 = NSURL(string: "/json.php", relativeToURL: baseURL)! // http://xxxxx.net/json.php

let baseURL2 = NSURL(string:"http://xxxxx.net/api/")! // http://xxxxx.net/api/

let url3 = NSURL(string: "json.php", relativeToURL: baseURL2)! // http://xxxxx.net/api/json.php
let url4 = NSURL(string: "/json.php", relativeToURL: baseURL2)! // http://xxxxx.net/json.php
```